# Packages installed in Spyder not showing up in Sublime text (OS High Sierra)

Tags: python, pip, sublimetext3, spyder

I installed two packages in Spyder through the IPython console using `pip install <package name>` , and the installed packages work fine in Spyder. However, when I run the same script in Sublime Text, it throws an error saying that the required packages are not installed. Can anyone please suggest a workaround so that I do not have to reinstall the same package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have multiple versions of python on your computer?
If so, make sure that you are using the same interpreter in Spyder which you also have installed your packages on using pip.

Comment: How do I check if there are multiple versions of python on my computer?

Comment: You can look for it in your explorer. Supposing you installed it on your C: drive the path might look like this:

C:\Users\{NAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python

If there is more than one folder called Python38 or Python 37 or sth, you have multiple versions.

Comment: I am on Mac OS High Sierra, and I just checked, I have two folders named anaconda3, ```/Users/ranjan/anaconda3``` and ```/Users/ranjan/opt/anaconda3```. Please let me know what I am supposed to do, I am new to setting environments.

Comment: Ok, so you're using anaconda. I assume you are using an anaconda interpreter in spyder, have you tried installing the packages you want in your anaconda client in the environments tab on the left side -> search packages? if you find them there try installing and running your program again. If you cannot find your packages try running the base(root) in the anaconda client -> environment tab and installl them using pip.

Comment: I found both the packages there, you mention that  " if you find them there try installing and running your program again."-- Could you please elaborate a bit, I mean which program you are referring to, and how to install? Thank a lot!

Comment: Im sorry, i meant that you should install the packages in the client and the run your script/program or whatever youre trying to do in spyder with the packages again. Like `import {package}` and run it. If it works you should be fine

Comment: I think there is a confusion. I meant that the installed packages run in Spyder, but not in Sublime. How can I get the packages installed through Spyder to work in Sublime?

Comment: My bad, could you please go into your Sublime Text Editor and run this:

    import sys
    print(sys.version)

It spits out the python version you are using.
Then go to your ipython console and print `python` - if it is the same python version you use in Sublime Text, run `pip install {package}`.

If it's not, can u tell me which python version Sublime Text is using?

Comment: I checked: Sublime is on ```2.7.10``` and Spyder is on ```3.7.6```

Comment: Ok, so you installed your packages for the version 3.7.6. So either you try to install the packages for python 2.7.10 or you change the python version used in sublime to 3.7.6, which is probably easier.
This is explained here:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/select-which-version-of-python-to-run-build/1695

or here:

https://medium.com/@hariyanto.tan95/set-up-sublime-text-3-to-use-python-3-c845b742c720